# Two sets of aligned equations in two columns?

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, two-column

Say I have a set of equations:

(1)

```
\begin{align}
wx&=u\\
wy&=v\\
w&=10
\end{align}
```

(2)

```
\begin{align}
x&=u/w\\
y&=v/w\\
\end{align}
```

How can I do the following: put (1) and (2) in the same line but in two separate columns,
and add a `\leftrightarrow` between them? i.e., something like

[image]

I tried putting (1) (2) and arrow in three `minipage` environments, but the width of `minipage` is hard to tune when (1) (2) have different width and looks quite ugly as above.

Comment: Are the numbers (1) and (2) part of an enumeration, or do they reference the equation using something like a `\label`?

Comment: (1) and (2) are just used to refer to the two block of equations in this article, I want to put the two blocks in one line.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try the `aligned` environment from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}[c]
wx&=u\\
wy&=v\\
w&=10
\end{aligned}
\qquad\Longleftrightarrow\qquad
\begin{aligned}[c]
x&=u/w\\
y&=v/w\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 32):

Also from the `amsmath` package, and closely related to Ian Thompson's answer, is one using the `split` environment:

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    wu &= ax+by+c\\
    wv &= dx+ey+f\\
    w &= gx+hy+i
  \end{split}
\quad\leftrightarrow\quad
  \begin{split}
    ax+by+c-xug-uyh-ui &= 0\\
    dx+ey+f-xvg-yvh-vi &= 0
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

For the sake of completeness, and perhaps an educative measure in terms of boxing (since the OP mentioned it), here's some `minipage` usage:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Here is some preceding text:
\[
\begin{minipage}{.35\linewidth}
  \centering
  $\begin{array}{r@{{}\mathrel{=}{}}l}
    wx & u \\[\jot]
    wy & v \\[\jot]
    w  & 10
  \end{array}$
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
\centering (1)~$\leftrightarrow$~(2)
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.35\linewidth}
  \centering
  $\begin{array}{r@{{}\mathrel{=}{}}l}
    x & u/w \\[\jot]
    y & v/w
  \end{array}$
\end{minipage}
\]
Here is some text following the above boxed expression.
\end{document}
```

Note that the `minipage` widths sum to `\linewidth` and are evenly distributed across it. The use of `array`s just make the vertical alignment easier.

If you're interested in seeing the boxes used in the above construction, wrap each `minipage` inside an `\fbox` (after setting `\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}` to avoid changes when visualizing the boxes):

[image]

Comment: This is the original approach I wanna try, however later I think  hand-tuning and hardcoding the width of minipage may not a good idea. Thanks anyway.