# How to create enumerate items in one line

Tags: enumerate

[image]

how can i create items in one line like on picture?

Comment: Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239442/218142

Comment: And welcome to TeX SE!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `multenum` package to typeset stuff like the way your image shows. From the documentation,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multienum}

\begin{document}

\begin{multienumerate}
\mitemxxxx{Not}{Linear}{Not}{Quadratic}
\mitemxxxo{Not}{Linear}{Not}
\mitemxx{$(x_1,x_2)=(2+\frac{1}{3}t,t)$ or
$(s,3s-6)$}{$(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(2+\frac{5}{2}s-3t,s,t)$}
\mitemx{$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=
(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{5}{4}s+\frac{3}{4}t-u,s,t,u)$
or $(s,t,u,\frac{1}{4}-s+\frac{5}{4}t+\frac{3}{4}u)$}
\mitemxxxx{$(2,-1,3)$}{None}{$(2,1,0,1)$}{$(0,0,0,0)$}
\end{multienumerate}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another method is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
   (a) & \lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (3,4)} \frac{2 - xy}{x^2 + y^2}, \\
   (b) & \lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (1,0)} \frac{\ln(x + e^{y})}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}, 
  \end{split}
\quad \quad
  \begin{split}
   (c) & \lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (1,0)} \left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{x^2/(x+y)}, \\
   (d) & \lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x y}{\sqrt{2 \, x^2 + y^2}}, 
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

which gives the result:
[image]

This answer is based on the work presented in [this solution by qubyte](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45664)